# How to configure the --public-host to run angular universal app behind nginx reverse proxy?

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I want to run a universal app with HMR and I am basing this question on the assumption its actually posssible.

I've set up and run a default "ng new" angular 8 application and works as expected. To run it behind a reverse proxy i am running with modified npm start

```
e.g. { "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3604 --disable-host-check --public-host //domain.com/spa/sockjs-node/" }
```

and I am using nginx to route domain.com/spa/sockjs-node/ to domain.com:3604/sockjs-node

this works fine and I have HMR working behind the nginx reverse proxy.

I wish to run an angular universal app with HMR alongside but I cant figure how to set the --public-host //domain.com/universal/sockjs-node/ for the universal application as its obviously no longer using ng serve to run. Without this set angular is not inserting the /universal/ section of path when searching for assets and sockets.

So my question in this context is: How do i set the --public-host for an angular universal app?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

works with following alterations to create-react-app default settings and nginx.

## index.html

```
add <base href="/ssr/"> in <head>
```

## nginx.default.conf

```
server ...
{

    location ^~ /ssr/sockjs-node/ {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3604/sockjs-node/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }
     location ^~ /ssr/ {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3604/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

## server.ts

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3604;
```